# How does one work with flows in hilbertspaces

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces

I was wondering how one works with vectorfields on Hilbertspaces in the sense that

1) When does the flow of such a field exist locally?

2) When is the flow complete.

Any good references to work with would be appreciated.

Comment: Hilbert spaces are in particular Banach, and so, the usual theorems about ODEs still hold in them. Hence, any smooth (or regular enough) vector field has a local flow.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Are their particular difficulties i have to take in consideration?